# Calling ViewDidAppear from numerous methods to update NSMutableDictionary data entries

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am fairly new to Objective C and am attempting to develop an app using Xcode5.

I am storing strings (either composed of numbers 1-9 or N/A) in a `NSMutableDictionary`.

When users get to the "Review your inputed results page" I want them to be able to manually go into a text field, delete the value present and retype their new value if necessary. However, I don't know how to reload this information into the system so that the new values will carry over into the email client, which basically sends the results to whatever email address the user wishes.

Currently, the values are being loaded using `ViewDidAppear` upon entering the `UIView`, but I think I need to call it again if, for example, `textField1` is updated.

I have methods for all the `textFields` that are `textField`(insert correct number here)IsUpdated and inside those I want to store the new value to the `NSMutableDictionary` (which I believe I can already do).

The issue is I cannot figure out how to get the current version of the dictionary that was loaded upon entering the `UIView` to update so that the information in `ViewDidAppear` updates for the email.

Hope that made sense.
As I said, definitely new to Objective C.
Below is the `viewDidAppear` method.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];

    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSMutableDictionary *results = [app results];

    NSString *firstResult = [results valueForKey:@"first"];
    NSString *secondResult = [results valueForKey:@"second"];
    NSString *thirdResult = [results valueForKey:@"third"];

    if ([firstResult isEqual: @"N/A"]) {
        self.Result1.text = results[@"first"];
    } else {
        int firstResultInt = [firstResult intValue]; firstResultInt++;
        [_Result1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", firstResultInt]];
    }

    if ([secondResult isEqual: @"N/A"]) {
        self.Result2.text = results[@"second"];
    } else {
        int secondResultInt = [secondResult intValue]; secondResultInt++;
        [_Result2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", secondResultInt]];
    }

    if ([thirdResult isEqual: @"N/A"]) {
        self.Result3.text = results[@"third"];
    } else {
        int thirdResultInt = [thirdResult intValue]; thirdResultInt++;
        [_Result3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", thirdResultInt]];
    }

    self.diningResult.text = results[@"dining"];
    self.basementResult.text = results[@"basement"];
    self.atticResult.text = results[@"attic"];
    self.carResult.text = results[@"car"];
    self.hallwayResult.text = results[@"hallway"];
    self.garageResult.text = results[@"garage"];
    self.other1Result.text = results[@"other"];
    self.other2Result.text = results[@"other1"];
    self.other1Name.text = results[@"other1name"];
    self.other2Name.text = results[@"other2name"];

    NSMutableString * str = [NSMutableString new];

    [str appendString:@"Bedroom: "];
    if ([firstResult isEqual: @"N/A"]) {
        [str appendString: firstResult];
    } else {
        int firstResultInt = [firstResult intValue]; firstResultInt++;
        NSString *firstResultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",firstResultInt];
        [str appendString: firstResultString];
    }

    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    [str appendString:@"Living Room: "];
    if ([secondResult isEqual: @"N/A"]) {
        [str appendString: secondResult];
    } else {
        int secondResultInt = [secondResult intValue]; secondResultInt++;
        NSString *secondResultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",secondResultInt];
        [str appendString: secondResultString];
    }

    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    [str appendString:@"Kitchen: "];
    if ([thirdResult isEqual: @"N/A"]) {
        [str appendString: thirdResult];
    } else {
        int thirdResultInt = [thirdResult intValue]; thirdResultInt++;
        NSString *thirdResultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",thirdResultInt];
        [str appendString: thirdResultString];
    }

    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    [str appendString:@"Dining:"];
    [str appendString:self.diningResult.text];
    [str appendString:@"\n"];

    //Code goes on to do the same with all other fields. all strings led by "str" get transferred over to the email

    self.emailString = [NSString stringWithString:str];
}
```

Comment: [Don't abuse the AppDelegate](http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/).

Comment: You don't need to worry about `reload` as such, since you are working with pointers, they will be directly updated with a `NSMutableDictionary` if you just do `[dic setObject:newValue forKey:key];` however you should not call viewDidAppear from your own, its a `UIViewController` `life-cycle` method, should be called automatically, rather you should put all your code in a function and call when you require..

Answer (score 2):

The code should not call `viewDidAppear`, it's the responsibility of the framework to call `viewDidAppear` at the appropriate times.  Instead, you should make a separate methods, e.g. `UpdateMailContents` and `UpdateTextFields`.  Then call those methods from `viewDidAppear`, and call `UpdateMailContents` from the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method of the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Comment: user speaks truth. You should never call viewDidAppear yourself.

Comment: How would I call those methods from viewDidAppear? Implicitly declaring one function from another is prohibited